# Convert s3 Image to Canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-s3, canvas

Code:

```
   var myCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      myCanvas.width = 596;
      myCanvas.height = 350;
      var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

      var img = new Image();
      img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
      img.src = url;

      img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      };

      let dt = myCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');

      var aLink = document.createElement('a');
      aLink.href = dt;
      aLink.download = 'fixed_photo.jpg';
      aLink.click();
```

Result:

It Downloads an empty Canvas instead of the image from the url. my guess it has something to do with s3 permission, i am using the getObject of S3 aws-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the developer tools in your web browser and check the network tab. It should let you know if the request failed and the status code.